# How to rewind a file descriptor using only system calls?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I have this sample code where I'm trying to implement for my operating systems assignment a program that copies the contents of an input file to an output file. I'm only allowed to use POSIX system calls, stdio is forbidden.
I've thought about storing the contents in a buffer but in my implementation I must know the file descriptor contents size. I googled a little and found about

```
off_t fsize;
fsize = lseek (input, 0, SEEK_END);
```

But in this case my file descriptor (input) gets messed up and I can't rewind it to the start. I played around with the parameters but I can't figure a way to rewind it back to the first character in the file after using lseek. That's the only thing I need, having that I can loop byte by byte and copy all the contents of input to output.

My code is here, it's very short in case any of you want have to take a look:

https://github.com/lucas-sartm/OSAssignments/blob/master/copymachine.c

Comment: `lseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET)`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov that did not work. Tried before and for some reason the pointer goes one or two characters after the first one. Go figure.

Comment: You don't need to rewind anything for this assignment. Nor do you need to content size. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I thought I did, it was a way of knowing how many bytes my input file had, thus allowing me to loop over and copy just that many times, avoiding any junk in the buffer...

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out by trial and error. All that was needed was to read the documentation and take a look at read() return values... This loop solved the issue.

```
while (read (input, &content, sizeof(content)) > 0){ //this will write byte by byte until end of buffer!

     write (output, &content, sizeof(content));

}
```

Comment: That's not correct either. Assuming you have `int count;` it should be `while ((count = read(input, &content, sizeof content)) > 0) { write(output, &content, count); }`. At present you are transferring junk at the end of the file (at least).

Comment: @EJP, funny enough, it didn't copy any junk to the new file using the method I thought about. Still, switched to yours since it makes more sense and is more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your file was an exact multiple of the buffer size.